# Skip Error Messages In Batch Scripts

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a very simple batch script.

```
Start "" "C:\Game.exe"
```

If Game.exe does not exist, it will show an error message that there is no game.exe. I want to skip such messages, I mean if game.exe exists it runs it and if no nothing.

How to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if exist "C:\Game.exe" Start "" "C:\Game.exe"
```

Answer (score 2):

For example like this:

if not exist "C:\Game.exe" goto ERROR1

Start "" "C:\Game.exe"

:ERROR1